# Make an Android SQLite call from a class: "The method open() is undefined for the type GameView.SQLiteAdapter"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have looked at several sample projects and I was able to create and update a database from my GameActivity class. However, I really need to make the database calls from my GameView class. The code for the GameActivity and GameView classes are below.

The problem I am having is that when I try to make a call to the database in the Gameview like this:

```
mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(context);
mySQLiteAdapter.open();
```

I get an error that says "The method open() is undefined for the type GameView.SQLiteAdapter".

I also tried opening the SQLiteAdapter class with this code:

```
Intent gameIntent = new Intent(myContext,AndroidSQLite.class);
gameIntent.putExtra("Move", "22");
myContext.startActivity(gameIntent);
```

However, it also opens up a new instance of the view which I don't want. What is the proper way to create a database connection in the GameView code?

GameActivity.class

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
 private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int skill = 0;
    int selectMove = 0;
    skill = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("Logic"));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("FGHIJK");
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
    GameView gView = new GameView(this, skill);

    gView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    gView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    setContentView(gView);
}
}
```

GameView.class

```
public class GameView extends View {

private Context myContext;
private int[][] moves = new int[9][3];
private int[] moveOrder = new int[9];
private Bitmap gameBoard;
private Bitmap gameBoardTrans;


private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

public GameView (Context context, int logic){
    super(context);
    myContext = context;

    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(context);
    mySQLiteAdapter.open();

    scale = myContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;  
    redPaint = new Paint();
    redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    redPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    redPaint.setTextSize(scale*15);
    for (int a=0;a<=8;a++){
        moves[a][0] = 0;
        }
    for (int b=0;b<=8;b++){
        moveOrder[b] = 0;
        }       
    //CompMove = new Random().nextInt(9);
}

 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        int X = (int)event.getX();
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        Intent gameIntent = new Intent(myContext,AndroidSQLite.class);
        gameIntent.putExtra("Move", "22");
        myContext.startActivity(gameIntent);


        switch (eventaction) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        if(X >=  screenW/7 && X <= 2*screenW/7 && Y >= screenH - screenH/8 && Y <= screenH) {
            skill = 0;
            System.out.println("Skill: " + skill);
        } else if (X >=  3*screenW/7 && X <= 4*screenW/7 && Y >= screenH - screenH/8 && Y <= screenH)   {
            skill = 1;
            System.out.println("Skill: " + skill);              
        } else if (X >=  5*screenW/7 && X <= 6*screenW/7 && Y >= screenH - screenH/8 && Y <= screenH)   {
            skill = 2;
            System.out.println("Skill: " + skill);  
        } else if (X >=  screenW/3 && X <= 2*screenW/3 && Y >= screenH - screenH/4 && Y <= screenH - screenH/4 + screenW/6) {


            gameComplete = true;
            order = 0;
            //int[][] moves = new int[9][3];
            //int[] moveOrder = new int[9];
            //int[] win = new int[5];
            //int[] outCome = new int[5];


            for (int c=0;c<=8;c++){
                    for (int d=0;d<=2;d++){
                        moves[c][d] = 0;
                    }
                }
            for (int e=0;e<=8;e++){
                moveOrder[e] = 0;
                }
            for (int f=0;f<=4;f++){
                win[f] = 0;
                }   
            for (int g=0;g<=4;g++){
                outCome[g] = 0;
                }   


            invalidate();

        }

        if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
            //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order])); = new SQLiteAdapter2(myContext);
            //mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
            //mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

            if(X >=  screenW*0/3 + 2 && X <= screenW*1/3 && Y >= screenW*0/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*1/3 + 2){
                if(moves[0][0] != 10 && moves[0][0] != 11){
                moves[0][0] = 10;
                moves[0][1] = 0;
                moves[0][2] = 0;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Move" + Integer.toString(order-1) + "," + Integer.toString(moveOrder[order-1]));
                //System.out.println("Data Move:" + moveOrder[order]);
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                System.out.println(" Next First:" + moves[0][0] + "-" + moves[1][0] + "-" + moves[2][0]);
                outCome = CheckForWin();
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*1/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*2/3 && Y >= screenW*0/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*1/3 + 2){
                if(moves[1][0] != 10 && moves[1][0] != 11){
                moves[1][0] = 10;
                moves[1][1] = 1;
                moves[1][2] = 0;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                System.out.println(" Next First:" + moves[0][0] + "-" + moves[1][0] + "-" + moves[2][0]);
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*2/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*3/3 && Y >= screenW*0/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*1/3 + 2){
                if(moves[2][0] != 10 && moves[2][0] != 11){
                moves[2][0] = 10;
                moves[2][1] = 2;
                moves[2][2] = 0;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                outCome = CheckForWin();
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*0/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*1/3 && Y >= screenW*1/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*2/3 + 2){
                if(moves[3][0] != 10 && moves[3][0] != 11){
                moves[3][0] = 10;
                moves[3][1] = 0;
                moves[3][2] = 1;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                System.out.println(" Next First:" + moves[3][0] + "-" + moves[1][0] + "-" + moves[2][0]);
                outCome = CheckForWin();
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*1/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*2/3 && Y >= screenW*1/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*2/3 + 2){
                if(moves[4][0] != 10 && moves[4][0] != 11){
                moves[4][0] = 10;
                moves[4][1] = 1;
                moves[4][2] = 1;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                System.out.println(" Next First:" + moves[0][0] + "-" + moves[1][0] + "-" + moves[2][0]);
                outCome = CheckForWin();
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*2/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*3/3 && Y >= screenW*1/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*2/3 + 2){
                if(moves[5][0] != 10 && moves[5][0] != 11){
                moves[5][0] = 10;
                moves[5][1] = 2;
                moves[5][2] = 1;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                System.out.println(" Next First:" + moves[0][0] + "-" + moves[1][0] + "-" + moves[2][0]);
                outCome = CheckForWin();
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*0/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*1/3 && Y >= screenW*2/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*3/3 + 2){
                if(moves[6][0] != 10 && moves[6][0] != 11){
                moves[6][0] = 10;
                moves[6][1] = 0;
                moves[6][2] = 2;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                outCome = CheckForWin();
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*1/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*2/3 && Y >= screenW*2/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*3/3 + 2){
                if(moves[7][0] != 10 && moves[7][0] != 11){
                moves[7][0] = 10;
                moves[7][1] = 1;
                moves[7][2] = 2;
                moveOrder[order] = 10;
                //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                order += 1;
                outCome = CheckForWin();
                if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                    makeComputerPlay();
                }
                }
            } else if (X >=  screenW*2/3 + 2 && X <=  screenW*3/3 && Y >= screenW*2/3 + 2 && Y <= screenW*3/3 + 2){
                if(moves[8][0] != 10 && moves[8][0] != 11){
                    moves[8][0] = 10;
                    moves[8][1] = 2;
                    moves[8][2] = 2;
                    moveOrder[order] = 10;
                    //mySQLiteAdapter.insert(Integer.toString(moveOrder[order]));
                    order += 1;
                    outCome = CheckForWin();
                    if(outCome[0] != 10 && outCome[0] != 11){
                        makeComputerPlay();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //mySQLiteAdapter.close();

    }


        invalidate();
        return true;
        }


 private void endGame() {
     int[][] moves = new int[9][3];
     int[] moveOrder = new int[9];
     int[] win = new int[5];
     int[] outCome = new int[5];
     order = 0;
     gameStart = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Are you sure all of it is relevant to your problem?

Comment: I removed most of the code that was irrelevant to this issue. I really just need to make database calls from the switch case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: event. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it compiles but won't run, it looks like a classpath problem.
I see you override a method that receives a Bundle, are you running on an OSGI framework?
In that case, you might have a classloading problem.

Comment: It appears to have trouble finding the SQLiteAdapter class. The “mySQLiteAdapter.open();” statement gives me the following error “The method open() is undefined for the type SQLiteAdapter”. It looks like it doesn’t like the context value I am giving it. It seems to be looking for the SQLiteAdapter class in the GameView class and not looking for it in its own class.

Comment: Is it compiling? What library/version is SQLiteAdapter class coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I simply was calling the wrong function name in my SQLiteAdapter.class file. It shouldn't have been "mySQLiteAdapter.open". It should have been "SQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();".

I was able to write to the database successfully once I used the right name(openToWrite).

This question was a simple type-o but it does show how you can make database calls from a class that extends view instead of one that extends activity. That might be of some use to others.